# odc connection error via LocaleIdentifier

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, xml

On the network drive I have an `xlsx` file with a `OLAP Pivot` in it.
This file uses a connection in a seperate `odc` file that is saved on the same network drive.
Several people have access to both of these files and in general everyone can open the Excel file and refresh the data.

One user when hitting Refresh always gets the following error:

[image]

Is this due to a setting on the user's pc or in the user's Excel settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. Go to Windows > Control Panel > Region and Language
2. Update the Format to “English (United States)”

Region and Language Format

3. Click Apply
4. Update the Format back to your original language, in my case “English (Australia)”
5. Click Apply
6. Click OK

[Source](http://www.dstewart.com.au/2012/08/xml-for-analysis-parser-localeidentifier-property/)